# Substitute baking powder for yeast in a focaccia?

Tags: dough, yeast, focaccia

I was going to make a focaccia-like dish, but found that I don't have any yeast. Can I substitute it with baking powder? How?

Comment: So buy yeast. Another formula, would create something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:  no, you cannot without radically changing the recipe until it is something completely different.

See my answer here for more information:  https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/32294/14401

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to make a flatbread-type of thing instead.

Comment: I have two spare jars of yeast to prevent this problem :-)  You could try a soda bread if you have buttermilk and baking soda around....