# yeastless bread help!

Tags: baking, substitutions, bread

My family has been trying to get away from using yeast.  So I've been experimenting with using baking powder and baking soda as a leavening agent in my bread loaves.  Our first loaf was very salty!  I don't see why you would need salt in the bread especially when baking soda and baking powder has such a salty base/flavor.  I have had other loaves that resulted in less saltiness, but then I run the problem of it not baking properly being doughy in the middle no matter how long I bake it.  I'm not certain if my loaves are too big and using the baking powder/soda is resulting in the necessity of smaller loaves.  Hope this is enough info for some help please??

Comment: Why are you trying to get away from using yeast? Depending on the reason, sourdough might be a solution for you.

Answer (score 4):

Yeast raised doughs, and quickbreads (chemically leavened doughs) have very different basic chemistries (see the answers to the linked reference question for much more detail).

You cannot simply convert one into the other.

I suggest you search for breads designed to be quickbreads, such as Irish Soda bread.

See also:

- [Why are there no recipes combining both yeast and baking powder?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/32291/why-are-there-no-recipes-combining-both-yeast-and-baking-powder)