# Can yogurt be used as a substitute for yeast in pizza dough?

Tags: substitutions, pizza, yeast, yogurt

I am making some pizza dough, but I don't have the yeast, is there a way to substitute it with yogurt? If so what proportions would I use, to keep the dough at the same consistency.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [yeast substitutes and proper measurements](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/49012/yeast-substitutes-and-proper-measurements)

Answer (score 10):

No, the bacteria in yogurt will not serve as the primary leavening agent for dough.