# I added yeast to a recipe calling for baking soda, what will happen?

Tags: yeast, baking-powder, baking-soda

I have added yeast to a recipe that also calls for baking soda and baking powder. I am curious what will happen to the bread?

I combined a bread maker recipe with a gluten free walnut cranberry rolls. I just took them out of the oven and although they look good they didn't rise much. I mixed the gluten free with yeast as instructed but was dry so I opened up recipe from my bread maker which called for baking soda and baking powder.

Comment: Can you give us a little more detail exactly what you did during the steps when you made the dough itself?

Comment: Baking soda and baking powder won't really help much with dryness. I find that most gluten-free flours seem to be very "thirsty" and the same recipe made with gluten-free v flour instead of wheat is often quite dry. If I'm expecting this, I sometimes start off with less flour, if it surprises me, I add more liquid (water, oil, egg, etc) to fix the texture. Gluten-free baked goods often don't rise as much as their wheat-based cousins either. If you include xanthan and/or guar gum it can help the texture to seen more like regular bread.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are there no recipes combining both yeast and baking powder?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/32291/why-are-there-no-recipes-combining-both-yeast-and-baking-powder)

Answer (score 1):

Yeast is a levening agent that needs some time to do its job. It eats sugar and makes CO2 gas to ride your bread.

Baking soda and baking powder are chemical levening agents. They'll make your bread rise while its baking.

If you out in yeast as well as BP and/or BS, and you bake it right away, probably nothin will happen and it will be a bit more nutritive, if you wait, you might find yourself with a handful of a mess when it rises way too much.

Answer (score 0):

Baking soda/powder and yeast work in two different ways. Yeast work off of the sugar in the flour (French baguettes) or like most other breads, work off of the added sugar.

Baking soda/powder react with acid to make the bread rise. That's why recipes often call for buttermilk. It's a source of acid. These doughs should not be over-worked (kneaded).

As long as your dough is not too acidic, the yeast will survive and work off of the sugars. If there's no acid in the dough, the baking soda/powder won't do much. If the dough is too acidic, it may kill the yeast.

I also make sourdough bread which can be very acidic. Even with the high acidity, the yeast still survives quite nicely, although a properly made sourdough takes much longer to rise.
My sourdough takes a day and a half to make. I use no added sugar. The rise comes completely from the natural sugar in the flour.

Short answer: I don't see any reason to use both yeast and baking soda/powder but I doubt any harm will come from it.